# How I can restore missed commits?

Tags: git

Some time ago I didn't check the configuration of one of the local git client after changing the remote repository url and then I pushed some local changes to remote git repository before I changed it and continue developing.

Now I haven't some commits in the actual repository but I have actual files locally.

How I can restore missed commits?

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (7726/7726), done.
dangling blob 4b811ed6c4c512e400399736869bccf0110b28c9
dangling tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
dangling blob 5f93f15a1d2dbf9fe65429e9124987208cdbe715
dangling commit 9c1434d01260873de6122f5fbd428c5eaec75761
dangling blob e6a2e5c880c410e98fc5803a77c6f16b6ffc3291
dangling tree c3b8e7abfe8455ed916113703890c1e355a123f5
dangling blob 794c7b37a217aa9b32f4f461a7ebc495d8c562f6
dangling tree 4b5224923fa2349a72372fd434e4fdf476680e0e
dangling blob bb5661ad15eebff39ddf7f462133a2e3c7492e48
dangling blob ddd70eadd066bcd63070545cbd2bb46d9e3735f5
dangling blob 2ed95453e41fc338db1db42b81fd19ad8e679ea4
dangling blob a95e284d68c4f01562b6ca9838076400500fd9fa
dangling tree f15f904c1cbdb0e7438466b29a4594aed23fe650
dangling blob 8c7b2a910b75e0fec826a8ce51c692a6be9c661f
```

After git merging with commits above I have:

```
# On branch recover-prod
# Your branch and 'origin/recover-prod' have diverged,
# and have 12 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git merge` to restore the deleted commits to your working branch.  The output from `git fsck` from your questions shows one commit with a SHA-1 hash of `9c1434d`.  To merge this commit into your working branch type the following:

```
git checkout yourbranch
git merge 9c1434d
```

Keep in mind you may get merge conflicts when doing this, and you will have to resolve them one-by-one for each commit you restore.

Comment: I try to apply it, but some error occurs: Commit d63ce8cb5aa44a71448b2889af646ec8a52c9bfa is a merge but no -m option was given.

Comment: Updated my answer again.  Git cherry-pick is a pain if you are dealing with merge commits, because there is more than one parent.

Comment: Please do a `git pull` to get the latest changes to your `recover-prod` branch.  It looks like someone else has pushed in some changes to the remote since you last pulled.